# sublime console omit print output?

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Quick question, I used sublime to code python, when I print output of a list (a very long list), the console automatically omit some values in the middle of list with dot.

```
['yes' 'yes' 'yes' ..., 'no' 'no' 'no']
```

How can I see all the values in the list?

Comment: I read values from a csv file and saved as an array, I want to print this array, because this array is very long, 2000 values in this array, so the console omit values, how can I print the all values? I just use code 'print array'

Comment: weird i try print 40k len charater in list, never omit output

Comment: is it because I used numpy array to save data instead of using list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this before running your `print(array)` if you are on Python 3:

```
import sys
import numpy

numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```

Or this if you are on Python 2:

```
import sys
import numpy

numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxint)
```

Comment: yes, it worked, thanks so much...